# How do I create help using Eclipse Information Center for deployment as a WAR under Tomcat 7?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, osgi, war

I'm upgrading the help of a commercial product from tomcat 5 to tomcat 7 and am not able to get help deployed as a war, which was working previously. Tomcat is running under Java 1.7. I have followed the directions here:

http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fua_help_setup_infocenter.htm

There were further changes I needed to make to get things close to working, but I now have a "uses constraint violation". From the log:

```
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.help.webapp [5]
  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. 
Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.help.webapp [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.help.webapp"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.0.v20150425-0643"; singleton:="true"] 
because it is exposed to package 'javax.servlet.annotation' from resources org.eclipse.osgi 
[osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.100.v20150529-1857"; singleton:="true"] 
and javax.servlet [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.servlet"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.1.0.v201410161800"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.help.webapp [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.help.webapp"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.0.v20150425-0643"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.core.runtime)(&(bundle-version>=3.6.0)(!(bundle-version>=4.0.0))))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: org.eclipse.core.runtime
  org.eclipse.osgi [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.osgi"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.10.100.v20150529-1857"; singleton:="true"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.help.webapp [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.help.webapp"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.7.0.v20150425-0643"; singleton:="true"]
    import: (&(osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet)(version>=3.1.0))
     |
    export: osgi.wiring.package: javax.servlet; uses:=javax.servlet.annotation
    export: osgi.wiring.package=javax.servlet.annotation
  javax.servlet [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="javax.servlet"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="3.1.0.v201410161800"]
```

I have attached to the osgi console and get this from "ss":

```
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State Bundle
0   ACTIVE org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857
Fragments=44
1   ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709
2   ACTIVE org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.300.v20140518-1928
3   ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge_1.0.300.v20130327-1442
4   ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.300.v20130402-1529
5   INSTALLED org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.7.0.v20150425-0643
6   STARTING org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.0.v20150421-2214
7   ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406
8   STARTING org.eclipse.ant.core_3.4.0.v20150428-1928
9   ACTIVE org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
10  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.2.9.v20150224
11  STARTING org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.7.0.v20150330-2103
12  STARTING org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.300.v20141118-1725
13  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.io_9.2.9.v20150224
14  RESOLVED javax.el_2.2.0.v201303151357
15  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.300.v20150423-1356
16  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.2.9.v20150224
17  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.100.v20150423-1356
18  ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1503
19  STARTING org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723
20  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.1.0.v20150323-1312
21  STARTING com.ibm.icu_54.1.1.v201501272100
22  RESOLVED org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.0.v20150519-2006
23  ACTIVE org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.2.0.v20150519-1816
24  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20130327-1442
25  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_9.2.9.v20150224
26  RESOLVED kindred.help_1.9.3
27  RESOLVED org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v201101211721
28  STARTING org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.5.0.v20150421-2214
29  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.2.9.v20150224
30  RESOLVED com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.51.v201410302000
31  RESOLVED javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201112011158
32  RESOLVED org.eclipse.jetty.http_9.2.9.v20150224
33  RESOLVED org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201501141630
34  RESOLVED org.apache.lucene.analysis_3.5.0.v20120725-1805
35  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.500.v20150119-1358
36  RESOLVED org.eclipse.oomph.p2.doc_1.1.0.v20150609-0914
37  STARTING org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.300.v20150408-1437
38  RESOLVED javax.servlet_3.1.0.v201410161800
39  RESOLVED org.apache.lucene.core_3.5.0.v20120725-1805
40  STARTING org.eclipse.help.base_4.0.300.v20150603-2000
41  STARTING org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.800.v20130819-1716
42  ACTIVE org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
43  STARTING org.eclipse.help_3.6.0.v20130326-1254
44  RESOLVED org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.extensionbundle_1.3.0
Master=0
45  ACTIVE org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
```

Putting "diag 5" into the console gives the same information as shown above from the log. I have tried everything I could find to fix this (there was nothing specific to this problem that I could find). The most promising thing I found was to change Require-Bundle to Import-Package, which I have seen as a best practice. I don't understand the output in log and console well enough to figure out what I need to change, though, and my attempts so far have failed.

Here is the list of files from ../Catalina/localhost/help/eclipse/plugins:

```
com.ibm.icu_54.1.1.v201501272100.jar
com.jcraft.jsch_0.1.51.v201410302000.jar
javax.el_2.2.0.v201303151357.jar
javax.servlet_3.1.0.v201410161800.jar
javax.servlet.jsp_2.2.0.v201112011158.jar
MY-APP-help-1.9.3.jar
org.apache.commons.logging_1.1.1.v201101211721.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036.jar
org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605.jar
org.apache.jasper.glassfish_2.2.2.v201501141630.jar
org.apache.lucene.analysis_3.5.0.v20120725-1805.jar
org.apache.lucene.core_3.5.0.v20120725-1805.jar
org.eclipse.ant.core_3.4.0.v20150428-1928.jar
org.eclipse.core.contenttype_3.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar
org.eclipse.core.expressions_3.5.0.v20150421-2214.jar
org.eclipse.core.jobs_3.7.0.v20150330-2103.jar
org.eclipse.core.net_1.2.300.v20141118-1725.jar
org.eclipse.core.runtime_3.11.0.v20150405-1723.jar
org.eclipse.core.variables_3.2.800.v20130819-1716.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.app_1.3.300.v20150423-1356.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.7.0.v20150402-1709.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.100.v20141023-1406.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.1.0.v20150323-1312.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.300.v20130402-1529.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.2.0.v20150519-1816.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.http.servletbridge_1.0.300.v20130327-1442.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper_1.0.500.v20150119-1358.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.jsp.jasper.registry_1.0.300.v20130327-1442.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.preferences_3.5.300.v20150408-1437.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.0.v20150318-1503.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.security_1.2.100.v20150423-1356.jar
org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge.extensionbundle_1.3.0.jar
org.eclipse.help_3.6.0.v20130326-1254.jar
org.eclipse.help.base_4.0.300.v20150603-2000.jar
org.eclipse.help.webapp_3.7.0.v20150425-0643.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.http_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.io_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.2.9.v20150224.jar
org.eclipse.osgi_3.10.100.v20150529-1857.jar
org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.0.v20150519-2006.jar
org.eclipse.update.configurator_3.3.300.v20140518-1928.jar
```

where MY-APP-help-1.9.3.jar is the documentation plug-in for my product.
The directory ../Catalina/localhost/help/WEB-INF/lib contains only this file:

```
org.eclipse.equinox.servletbridge_1.3.0.v20140430-1556.jar
```

I thought it would be more helpful to show what was actually showing up in tomcat vs. what I am putting in the plug-in (it's almost the same, except for the ...extensionbundle...jar). I have spent far too much time just getting to this point and am completely frustrated and out of ideas for what else to try. Thanks for any help.